# visual studio code - how to comment multiple lines for html (each line instead whole block)

Tags: html, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

When I comment HTML files, VSCode wraps my selection and puts a single
`<!-- -->` tag around the whole selection.

How can I change it so that instead it comments every single line individually? (like e.g. in WebStorm)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any solution for this since asked?

Answer (score 4):

I made an extension that will do what you want: [Toggle Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments).

Using this keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+/",               // whatevefr keybinding you wish
    "command": "toggle-comments.toggleLineComments",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

[image: html comment each line separately demo]

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcut to comment multiple in Windows is 'Shift+Alt+A'.

Comment: This question was about Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Comment: This works with `Shift + Option + A` in Mac but not for each line. It is just as `Cmd + /` so I think this is not an answer (still no available answer after two years)

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyboard shortcut:

*`ctrl + shift + /`*